# Using indirect for a Sheet range in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sheets labeled 1,2,3,4,etc in Excel 2016

I can write a formula that reference a cell across several sheets. `=40-SUM('17:23'!D46)`

I am trying to create a reference that is going to be relative to a number by using a formula such as

```
=40-INDIRECT("SUM('"&AN3-7&":23'!D46)")
```

Where `AN3=24`. When using that, I get a #Ref error. Evaluation yields

```
=40-INDIRECT("SUM('17:23'!D46)")
```

Can this be done? also tried Indirect at the very beginning

```
=indirect("40-(sum('&AN3-7&":23'!D46)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
=40-SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT(ROW(INDIRECT(AN3-7&":23"))&"!D46")))
```

in place of your

```
=40-INDIRECT("SUM('"&AN3-7&":23'!D46)")
```

might not be the prettiest of functions, but I wasnt able to get it working without using double INDIRECT.

Comment: sorry for the delay had to put the project down and only now resuming. I will have to play around with that double indirect, I ended up breaking it out to look at each sheet individually. It is more visually pleasing as a result. But now I know that double indirects can exist